# Pandas/Python: Set value of new column based on row value and other DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

Is it possible to add a value in a column when the province name of second dataframe matches with the province name of the first dataframe? I searched for answers and weren't able to find anything useful for my case.

This is first DataFrame

```
    date        province            confirmed   released    deceased
0   2020-03-30  Daegu               6624        3837        111
1   2020-03-30  Gyeongsangbuk-do    1298        772         38
2   2020-03-30  Gyeonggi-do         463         160         5
3   2020-03-30  Seoul               426         92          0
4   2020-03-30  Chungcheongnam-do   127         83          0
...
```

and this is second DataFrame

```
    code    province            latitude    longitude
0   12000   Daegu               35.872150   128.601783   
1   60000   Gyeongsangbuk-do    36.576032   128.505599  
2   20000   Gyeonggi-do         37.275119   127.009466
3   10000   Seoul               37.566953   126.977977  
4   41000   Chungcheongnam-do   36.658976   126.673318
...
```

I would like to turn the first DataFrame like this.

```
    date        province            confirmed   released    deceased   latitude     longitude
0   2020-03-30  Daegu               6624        3837        111        35.872150    128.601783
1   2020-03-30  Gyeongsangbuk-do    1298        772         38         36.576032    128.505599
2   2020-03-30  Gyeonggi-do         463         160         5          37.275119    127.009466
3   2020-03-30  Seoul               426         92          0          37.566953    126.977977
4   2020-03-30  Chungcheongnam-do   127         83          0          36.658976    126.673318
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) method is what you want to use here.

**Using your example DataFrames:**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    date = [
        '2020-03-30','2020-03-30','2020-03-30',
        '2020-03-30','2020-03-30',],
    province = [
        'Daegu', 'Gyeongsangbuk-do', 'Gyeonggi-do', 
        'Seoul', 'Chungcheongnam-do'],
    confirmed = [6624, 1298, 463, 426, 127],
    released = [3837, 772, 160, 92, 83],
    deceased = [111, 38, 5, 0, 0],
))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    code = [12000, 60000, 20000, 10000, 41000],
    province = [
        'Daegu', 'Gyeongsangbuk-do', 'Gyeonggi-do', 
        'Seoul', 'Chungcheongnam-do'],
    latitude = [
        35.872150, 36.576032, 37.275119, 
        37.566953, 36.658976],
    longitude = [
        128.601783, 128.505599, 127.009466, 
        126.977977, 126.673318],
))

df3 =  df1.merge(
    df2[['province', 'latitude','longitude']],
    on = 'province',
)

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 7)

print(df3)
```

**Output:**

```
         date           province  confirmed  released  deceased   latitude  \
0  2020-03-30              Daegu       6624      3837       111  35.872150   
1  2020-03-30   Gyeongsangbuk-do       1298       772        38  36.576032   
2  2020-03-30        Gyeonggi-do        463       160         5  37.275119   
3  2020-03-30              Seoul        426        92         0  37.566953   
4  2020-03-30  Chungcheongnam-do        127        83         0  36.658976   

    longitude  
0  128.601783  
1  128.505599  
2  127.009466  
3  126.977977  
4  126.673318
```

[Example Code in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adf1%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20date%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'2020-03-30','2020-03-30','2020-03-30',%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'2020-03-30','2020-03-30',%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20province%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Daegu',%20'Gyeongsangbuk-do',%20'Gyeonggi-do',%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Seoul',%20'Chungcheongnam-do'%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20confirmed%20%3D%20%5B6624,%201298,%20463,%20426,%20127%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20released%20%3D%20%5B3837,%20772,%20160,%2092,%2083%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20deceased%20%3D%20%5B111,%2038,%205,%200,%200%5D,%0A%29%29%0A%0Adf2%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20code%20%3D%20%5B12000,%2060000,%2020000,%2010000,%2041000%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20province%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Daegu',%20'Gyeongsangbuk-do',%20'Gyeonggi-do',%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'Seoul',%20'Chungcheongnam-do'%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20latitude%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2035.872150,%2036.576032,%2037.275119,%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2037.566953,%2036.658976%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20longitude%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20128.601783,%20128.505599,%20127.009466,%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20126.977977,%20126.673318%5D,%0A%29%29%0A%0Adf3%20%3D%20%20df1.merge%28%0A%20%20%20%20df2%5B%5B'province',%20'latitude','longitude'%5D%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20on%20%3D%20'province',%0A%29%0A%0Apd.set_option%28'display.max_columns',%207%29%0A%0Aprint%28df3%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=17&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Comment: I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do is merge both the DataFrames based on the `province` column.

Make a new DataFrame which you want.

First run a loop on first DataFrame and add all the values in it. (Leave the values for the columns which are not present)

Then run a loop on second DataFrame and add the its values by comparing the value of `province` to the already added value in the new DataFrame.

Here's an example

NewDataFrame

```
date        province            confirmed   released    deceased   latitude     longitude
```

After adding the first DataFrame

```
    date        province            confirmed   released    deceased    latitude     longitude
0   2020-03-30  Daegu               6624        3837        111
1   2020-03-30  Gyeongsangbuk-do    1298        772         38
2   2020-03-30  Gyeonggi-do         463         160         5
3   2020-03-30  Seoul               426         92          0
4   2020-03-30  Chungcheongnam-do   127         83          0
```

After adding second DataFrame

```
    date        province            confirmed   released    deceased   latitude     longitude
0   2020-03-30  Daegu               6624        3837        111        35.872150    128.601783
1   2020-03-30  Gyeongsangbuk-do    1298        772         38         36.576032    128.505599
2   2020-03-30  Gyeonggi-do         463         160         5          37.275119    127.009466
3   2020-03-30  Seoul               426         92          0          37.566953    126.977977
4   2020-03-30  Chungcheongnam-do   127         83          0          36.658976    126.673318
```